# How to pass python object from one file module to another file module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to implement page object model in python and selenium. For that matter, I have two modules:

**LoginPage.py**

```
class LoginPage:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        '''do something with the self.driver object. 
           Example: Using self.driver.title() I can make sure if I am on the right page but it shows an error'''


    def Login(self, username, password):
        '''Use the same driver object for calling username and password objects of a page'''
```

**Program.py**

```
from selenium import webdriver

from LoginPage import *

class Program:

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")

    #While creating LoginPage object, I'm passing driver object which is actually a firefox instance.
    login = LoginPage(driver)
    homePage = login.Login("sample@gmail.com", "mypassword")

    if homePage is not None:
        print "In Home page"
```

***From the Program.py module, I am creating a Firefox driver and passing the reference to 'driver'. This 'driver' is passed as a parameter to `LoginPage()`.
The LoginPage.py is not able to make use of 'driver'. Can anyone help me find the mistake here?***

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "/media/Pinku/POMProject/src/Program.py", line 4, in <module> class Program: 
File "/media/Pinku/POMProject/src/Program.py", line 11, in Program login = LoginPage(driver) 
File "/media/Pinku/POMProject/src/LoginPage.py", line 5, in init if self.driver.title() == "Sign In": 
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

Comment: This should work - would you post the information on what error you are receiving please?

Comment: @Kisamoto: This is the error I am getting "TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable"

Comment: Please post the full traceback in your question

Comment: @Kisamoto: Hi,this is the trace I could generate "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/Pinku/POMProject/src/Program.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Program:
  File "/media/Pinku/POMProject/src/Program.py", line 11, in Program
    login = LoginPage(driver)
  File "/media/Pinku/POMProject/src/LoginPage.py", line 5, in __init__
    if self.driver.title() == "Sign In":
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right I see your problem:

It's very simple, in your `__init__` in `LoginPage` you are calling `self.driver.title()` however, as per the basic [selenium example](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) on their page, it is just `self.driver.title` (without the brackets).

`title` is an attribute rather than a callable method, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I can't believe parentheses was giving me a tough time all this while.. Your answer worked smooth..